# Causal inference: is it possible to estimate the actual users who did X because of Y?

Tags: causality

Suppose we have a dataset with many (~100) features and a binary outcome.  I am interested in not only assessing whether any given feature is causally related to the outcome, but in actually being able to say that users X,Y,and Z got the outcome specifically *because* of some specific feature(s).  Is this even possible?  If so, could someone please give me some pointers as to go about it (math, codes, packages, etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to CV. There is no math or code to determine causality. You should have an intervention study to make any claims of a causal relationship. The closest you could get is probably estimating an undirected graph of partial correlations, and then using a PC algorithm to determine direction here and there, but this still does not demonstrate causality, that is up to the study design.

Comment: Here is a math pointer: Pearl's work on causality.  https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r350.pdf. Page 136 and onward discusses whether and when questions like "did Z cause Y?" can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the problem of "probability of causation." It is not a major topic in the causal inference literature, but there has been some written on it. A Google search led me to [this CDC page](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ocas/faqspoc.html) on interpreting probability of causation and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05566) (Dawid, Musio, Murtas, 2017) on contemporary perspectives in probability of causation. The concept is used when attempting assign blame or responsibility for an event to some causal actor.